# phonegap facebook connect plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova

Havent't found any solution after hours of looking.

Using: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Xcode tells me the following:
"Cordova Facebook Connect plugin initialized successfully. "

After the facebook js sdk is initiated, I call FB.login(). Sometime during FB.login I get thrown a JS error (I do not get switched to the facebook app). I have no idea what kind of error because 'cordova-plugin-console' isn't working either (lovely).

Any ideas what possible errors might arise during FB.login?